# Training Validation Testing set split for facial expression dataset

Tags: validation, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) and I just want to ask if the way I split my training/validation/testing set is correct.

I have a total of 55 subjects. 
I plan to split them into 80–10–10 for training (45 subjects), validation (unseen 5 subjects), testing (unseen 6 subjects).

Should the validation set consists of unseen subjects as well? Or can I shuffle the whole training set and use a part of it (10-20%) as validation set?

I have read that using N-Fold cross-validation, the whole training set (instances) are shuffled then split into N-folds and the model is trained and averaged N times.
However, in the case for Neural Networks or CNN, we don't use cross-validation since it is very computationally expensive.

I'm just wondering which is correct since using a validation set of unseen subjects, my model starts to overfit after 3-5 epochs and doesn't learn at all.
On the other hand, if I use 10-20% of the training set as my validation set, my model learns with reasonable accuracy (45-50%) using a 3-layer CNN but when tested with the unseen testing set, my top-1 accuracy is around 15-16% only.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself when developing a CNN is if you have enough data to feed it. How many images are there per subject? If there are less than 100 then I suggest finding more training data is the right move. I would even suggest getting more than 10 000 training images.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz I have 500k data. Each subject has 100 video clips of expression, so in total 5500 video clips averaging around 2-5 seconds. Data is enough I think, what I'm asking is if the split is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, there is no rule; there's barely a rule of thumb.  Much of the work in developing a topology and a model is in tuning the hyper-parameters; the train-test-validate ratio is merely one of these.  Typical splits are *very* roughly 2:1:1, with plenty of variation, depending on the purpose and the data set.  I start to question the division if training is less than 50%, or either test or validate is less than 20% (although 15% is sometimes useful, especially if the data set is too small).

"Correct" depends very much on your ultimate purpose for the model.  If you expect it to handle new subjects, then of course you must include unseen subjects for both testing and validation.  If need only to discriminate well for the given subjects, then you'll want a balanced mix, perhaps 45:10:0 -- in this case, you would *welcome* over-fitting.

If you expect to handle expressions from the general population (new subjects), then I believe you're short of training subjects.  To properly tune such a model, you need enough that you're free to play with the proportions, and even something as slim as 8:1:1 should give you results you can recognize as useful.

Comment: Hi @Prune thank you very much for your answer. I was enlightened, I know nothing about purposes of models, maybe I should ask my adviser about this. However, is this a typo? "If need only to discriminate well for the given subjects, then you'll want a balanced mix, perhaps **45:10:0** -- in this case, you would welcome over-fitting." 45% for training, 10% for validation, and 45% for testing?

Comment: Sorry; that's 45 subjects to 10 subjects.  For validation, you can then use the entire input set of 55.

Comment: Thanks very much, I've tried creating a model for discriminating well for the given subjects (not the model for handling new subjects), I don't think I am over-fitting because after training, my accuracy on the whole validation data (10%) is around 50% while on the graph, it is around 70-75% with a batch size of 256. Am I doing it right? Also, i'm just wondering why should I use the entire input set of 55 as validation after training the model?

Comment: Using all 55 for validation applies when your objective is to fit exactly that set of subjects: you would *want* over-fitting then.

Comment: I still can't judge whether you're "doing it right".  I recommend that you tune your proportions: also try 60:20:20 and a couple other mixes to see what accuracy you get.  Batch size should have little effect on accuracy, except at the low end (batch size of 1-4, perhaps, or small and not shuffled); 256 should be fine.  The main considerations there are memory usage and multi-node communication (if you have a cluster).